# ASP.NET: Will cookies be deleted after expiry even though the page is not refreshed/reloaded

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an asp.net site.

I set like this, I worry if the page is not reloaded(keeping on the same page) the cookies won't be deleted after a day.

YourCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookies expires, not auto delete him self.

What is means expires ? the cookies stays there but if you ask for them again, and have expires, you just don't read them.

If the browser stays open and the cookie expires, the page is still there - the cookie is still there until you make refresh. If you need to close the user browser after the cookie expires, you need to add extra javasript call to verify that every few seconds or so.

If you wish to create something that deletes him self, then include on the cookie string, more information's encrypted, for example, include the datetime that you wish to "delete" them and then when you read that cookie, check that datetime and act accordingly. This is how the verification of user cookie works